# (2.81 Evee) Volumetric spotlight shows through solid object

Tags: eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

[image: See this here?]

I'm trying to add "real" spotlights to my scene, as in stage lighting. Naturally I want spotlight-looking objects present. Problem is, when I place the light inside the object, it still shows through. (see picture)

The reason I placed it inside , is if placed outside, it's very obvious the cone of light doesn't adhere to the diameter of the spotlight object. This way the diameters coincide. Meaning, it should obviously start from a circle, not a point. (once again, see picture for how the spotlight looks)

But how do I make it now show through? Or some other way of adding realistic spot light **that doesn't start from a point** (Evee)?